# DialogViewController not firing ViewDidDisappear

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a hierarchy like the following:

```
NavigationController
```

- Push first `ViewController` - `ViewDidDisappear` fires correctly when going to next view
- Push `DialogViewController` that has a list - `ViewDidDisappear` fires when going to next
- Each list opens a new `DialogViewController` - `ViewDidDisappear` never files
- There are some buttons on this one that opens another `DialogViewController` - `VidDidDisappear` never fires

Code:

```
 public partial class CustomDialogController : DialogViewController {

    public CustomDialogController() : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null, true) {
    }

    public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
        Console.WriteLine("Gone baby 2");
        // Never Fires
    }
  }

public partial class WorkoutsView : DialogViewController
{

    public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
        Console.WriteLine("Gone baby");
        // Here is where you can add your custom code for when the DialogViewController disappears
    }


    public WorkoutsView (MetaFitness.BL.MetaFitnessManager manager) : base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null, true)
    {
        this.Title ="Title";
        WorkoutViewModel WorkoutDetail = new WorkoutViewModel();
        //var bc = new BindingContext (this, WorkoutDetail, "Details");
        //detailView = new DialogViewController(bc.Root,true);
        List<Workout> workouts = manager.GetWorkouts ();

        var abc = new CustomDialogController();
        abc.Root = new RootElement("WorkoutsView");
        Root = abc.Root;
        Section section = new Section ("Workouts");
        foreach (var wo in workouts) {
            string name = string.Empty;

            CustomDialogController WorkoutController = new CustomDialogController();
            WorkoutController.Root = new RootElement(wo.Name);
            RootElement wSection = WorkoutController.Root;

            var s2 = new Section();
            var mvm2 = new MeasurementViewModel();
                            // the code for this is similar to CustomDialogController - never fires
            s2.Add(new MeasurementViewController(mvm2).Root);
            wSection.Add (s2);


            section.Add(wSection);  

        }
        Root.Add(section);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how to use `UINavigationController` and `DialogViewController`.
Keep the basic concept of `UIViewController` in mind: one controller handles a screenful of content (on iPhone). This means, you should push controllers on the `UIViewController's` stack. Each of these controllers can be `DialogViewControllers`.
Saying this you can already see that adding the view (Root) of `MeasurementViewModel` inside a section of `WorkoutsView` is a break of the concept above and hence, you're violating Apple's design rules and the result: your `View*()` methods won't be called.

Instead: add a callback on your elements and one of them can push a new controller on the navigation controller's stack.

You should be able to find all necessary documentation on MT.Dialog's Github page: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog or in the Xamarin blog: http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/10/easily-create-ios-user-interfaces-with-monotouch-dialog/

Comment: Thanks, that set me straight.